# ImportError: No Module named picklefield.fields (Yep pip install says it is there)

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am using `vagrant` to run my python environment. In my data models I am using `django-picklefield` module.

when I run my server it says

```
ImportError: No module named picklefield.fields.
```

I tried to uninstall and install the `picklefield` module. Still having the same problem.

Comment: Have you installed python setup tools. if not do it using sudo apt-get install python-setuptools and then sudo python setup.py install

Comment: I already installed them. And again I re-installed them. Still having same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able install via:

```
/[your python install directory]/bin/pip install django-picklefield
```

If you do this directly instead of a general pip call to install django-picklefield, that will ensure that it is installed on the correct version of Python.

Based on your description my best guess is that you have multiple versions of Python installed, and that your install/uninstall is happening on the wrong one.